# Fritz-John conditions: Equality-constrained case as special case of inequality constraints

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, global-optimization

In Chapter 4 of [Nonlinear Programming: Theory and Algorithms](http://books.google.com/books?id=qIRDEgYesVUC&pg=PA188&lpg=PA188&dq=we+have+observed+above+that+a+point+x+is+a+FJ+point&source=bl&ots=lpWTuDSrZM&sig=nd5wbPn2GqYAyE4SCQ7TygvoBWk&hl=en&ei=INtFTfawHZHmsQP4m5zWCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=we%20have%20observed%20above%20that%20a%20point%20x%20is%20a%20FJ%20point&f=false)  by Bazarra, Sherali, and Shetty, the following claim is made after Theorem 4.3.2 (Fritz-John necessary conditions):

"Note also that these conditions [FJ conditions for equality-constrained case] are not equivalently obtained by writing each equality constraint as two associated inequalities and then applying the FJ conditions for the inequality-constrained case."

I am having trouble seeing why this is: If I write down the corresponding FJ conditions for the inequality-constrained case (Theorem 4.2.8), I get *exactly* their Theorem 4.3.2, with $\nu_i=\mu_i-\mu_i'$, where $\mu_i$ is the multiplier associated with $h_i(x)\le 0$ and $\mu_i'$ is the multiplier associated with $h_i(x)\ge 0 \iff -h_i(x)\le 0$. Furthermore, due to the equality constraints, any feasible point is necessarily active for each of these inequality constraints.

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: As an aside: It is not "Fritz-John" conditions, it is "Fritz John" conditions. (It is named after one single person, whose last name is "John" and whose first name is "Fritz".)

Comment: Like the jeans from Levi Strauss, @WillieWong.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about understanding your question,
however as I know,
the author's comment on the equivalence between equality constraints and associated two inequality constraints is focused on the applicability of the Fritz John's theorem.

Let's consider the case that $h_i$'s are not affine. In this case, if $h_i$'s are convex, $-h_i$'s are not convex. Then, we can not apply the Fritz John's theorem.
In short, the author said that not for feasibility and activity, but for applicability of the theorem.